# Scanning for Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, network-scan

Can I scan for Bluetooth & Bluetooth LE devices at the same time onClick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Here is textual from:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#setup

Note: You can only scan for Bluetooth LE devices or scan for Classic Bluetooth devices, as described in Bluetooth. You cannot scan for both Bluetooth LE and classic devices at the same time.

I am developing apps for Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral devices.
The devices I design are using Bluetooth LE from Nordic Semiconductors and the apps are running in smartphones using Android 4.3+

Comment: Can I scan for (regular) Bluetooth and then connect with LE?

Comment: Please note that Bluetooth classic and LE has different set of API s. So the answer is NO.